# kubernetes creating stateful set , pods not started

Tags: kubernetes

I created a stateful set but after running `kubectl apply -f wordpress-database.yaml` and `kubectl get  statefulset` I see the pod is alwayson status zero (why?):

```
wordpress-database   0/1     25m
```

yaml (please do not consider alignment)

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: StatefulSet
metadata:
  name: wordpress-database
spec:
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: blog
  serviceName: "blog"
  replicas: 1
  template:
  metadata:
  labels:
    app: blog 
  spec:
  containers:
  - name: database
    image: mysql:5.7
    ports:
    - containerPort: 3306
    env:
    - name: MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD
      value: rootPassword
    - name: MYSQL_DATABASE
      value: database
    - name: MYSQL_USER
      value: user
    - name: MYSQL_PASSWORD
      value: password          
    volumeMounts:
    - name: data
      mountPath: /var/lib/mysql
  - name: blog
    image: wordpress:latest
    ports:
    - containerPort: 80
    env:
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_HOST
      value: 127.0.0.1:3306
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_NAME
      value: database
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_USER
      value: user
    - name: WORDPRESS_DB_PASSWORD
      value: password  
    volumeClaimTemplates:
    - metadata:
    name: data
    spec:
    resources:
    requests:
      storage: 1Gi
```

Comment: Please add the all line including `STATUS RESTART AGE` columns.also run `kubectl descripe pod` and add the relevant event area.

Comment: I strongly suspect your pod is waiting on the Persistent Volume Claim to be provisioned, since it is using `volumeClaimTemplate:` instead of an existing, established, Persistent Volume + Claim. It block indefinitely if you don't have a [default Storage Class provider](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/#provisioner) configured in your cluster

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Firstly to check what happend with your [statefulset](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/workloads/controllers/statefulset/) execute:

```
$ kubectl describe statefulset wordpress-database
```

You probably don't have storage provided, your persistent volume is not being created. Check if you have configured [storageclass](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/storage-classes/) or set it as default.

your **volumeClaimTemplates** section should looks similar:

```
 volumeClaimTemplates:
  - metadata:
      name: example
    spec:
      accessModes: [ "ReadWriteOnce" ]
      storageClassName: "your-storage-class"
      resources:
        requests:
          storage: 1Gi
```

Useful documentation: [PersistentVolumes](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/storage/persistent-volumes/).